# Captcha not been captured in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm facing difficulty passing thru the captcha system in this website http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8090/MiscQry/Pan_index.jsp

I need to input the IEC codes from a excel sheet and enter the Captcha and extract the table inside the Final result page.

1. 0913993340
2. 0915011433
3. 6315000983
4. 3115906005
5. 0411013530

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Public Sub IECsite()

   Dim bot As WebDriver
   'Dim VAL As String
   Dim count As Long

   Set bot = New WebDriver
   bot.Start "chrome"
   count = 1
   While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)

   bot.Get "http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8090/MiscQry/Pan_index.jsp"

   bot.FindElementById("panNo").SendKeys Range("A" & count)
   'bot.FindElementById("captVal").SendKeys "L3oTtiM"
   'VAL = InputBox("Enter the captcha value", "CAPTCHA", "")
   'If VAL = vbNullString Then
   'Exit Sub
   'End If
   'bot.FindElementById("captVal").SendKeys VAL
   bot.Wait 10000

   bot.FindElementById("submit").Click

   Range("N" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]").Text
   Range("O" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]").Text
   Range("P" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").Text
   Range("Q" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]").Text
   Range("R" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]").Text
   Range("S" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]").Text
   Range("T" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]").Text
   count = count + 1

   Wend
   bot.Quit

   End Sub
   ```

I have given a timeframe of 10 seconds to enter the Captcha manually.

Please review it and lemme know.

[image: Image1]

Any Ideas on extracting this table because if i use the Xpath method, i can't take the whole table at once and need to write a lengthy code, and most importantly it'll be tedious work for tables with multiple rows.

**NOTE:-** This table can consists of more than 1 row(sometimes 15 rows also)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of a captcha?

Comment: Remove equal sign `bot.FindElementById("captVal").SendKeys VAL`

Comment: I second @braX.

Comment: @braX Yes sir i do understand the purpose of it, but i'm trying to semi-automate the whole purpose.
 @Y - Thank you.
 @ Sam- hahah, i do get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Before running the code, you need to apply some steps first

** Install Tesseract-OCR from the link:
    https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
Add tesseract path To Environment Variables
To make sure installation is OK, check the version In PowerShell

```
tesseract --version
```

** Install ImageMagick From The Link:
    https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Add ImageMagick path To Environment Variables
In the command prompt run these lines

```
magick logo: logo.gif
magick identify logo.gif
magick logo.gif win:
```

** Open Windows PowerShell ISE then create new file, and put these lines (Change the username)

```
cd C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Desktop
magick convert Captcha.png -resize 400x100 -density 300 -quality 100 CaptchaNew.png
magick convert CaptchaNew.png -negate -lat 300x160+30% -negate CaptchaNew.png
tesseract.exe CaptchaNew.png OutCaptcha -l eng
```

Finally save the file on the desktop with the name "GetCaptcha" and the extension would be ps1.

** PowerShell should be configured to be able to run the scripts from it
so in PowerShell, run these commands

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Force
```

### The code

```
Public Sub Test_IECsite()
Dim e, bot As WebDriver, tbl As Selenium.TableElement, dlg As alert, obj As Object, lr As Long

Set bot = New WebDriver

With bot
    .Start "Chrome"

    For Each e In Array("0915011433", "6315000983")
        .Window.Maximize

backP:
        .Get "http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8090/MiscQry/Pan_index.jsp"
        Set obj = .FindElementById("capt").TakeScreenshot(3000)
        obj.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path + "\Captcha.png")

        .FindElementById("panNo").SendKeys e
        .FindElementById("captVal").SendKeys GetCaptcha
        .FindElementById("submit").Click

        Set dlg = .SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)
        If Not dlg Is Nothing Then dlg.accept: GoTo backP
        Set tbl = .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/center/table[2]").AsTable

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If lr > 1 Then lr = lr + 2
            With .Range("A" & lr).Resize(, 2)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .Font.Color = vbBlue
            End With
            With .Range("A" & lr + 1).Resize(, 7)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Color = vbRed
            End With

            tbl.ToExcel .Range("A" & lr)
        End With
    Next e

    Stop
End With
End Sub

Function GetCaptcha() As String
Dim wshShell As Object, sOutput As String, strCommand As String

sOutput = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\OutCaptcha.txt"
strCommand = "Powershell.exe -File ""C:\Users\" & Application.UserName & "\Desktop\GetCaptcha.ps1"""
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Run strCommand, 0, True

GetCaptcha = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sOutput).ReadAll, vbLf)(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info, i'll try it later, little busy now with other work.

Comment: Hi Sir,
I'm getting Error in the second last Line of code : GetCaptcha=Split........(this line)
It says 
" Run-Time error '53'
File not found

Comment: You have to test the work of the PowerShell file first to see if the conversion of the image is OK or not. Did you have "CaptchaNew.png" on the desktop when running the code?

Comment: Yes i did have the  "CaptchaNew.png" on the desktop.
I created a new file on PowerShell ISE via "Ctrl +N" , there i copied the code as you provided and saved the file as "GetCaptcha.ps1"

Comment: Try open the file GeCaptcha.ps1 with PowerShell ISE then run the lines inside it to see if you will get the output text file "OutCaptcha.txt" with the text from the image or not.

Comment: I have just  added a screenshot, could you please check it and tell me if i'm doing correctly.
 When i saved the file in the desktop, i reopened it via notepad to check what's in the file, and then now i opened it via PowershellISE , and then clicked on RUN, and this appeared.

Comment: I have updated the post as Powershell should be configured to be able to run the scripts.

Comment: I have added a new screenshot, there was a msgbox "for allowing outside scripts to run  access" i clicked on "Yes to All" .
Then this error popped up when i pressed Enter.

Comment: I clicked on "suspend" and then the result was "ByPass".
Later when i ran  the whole code in VBA, i got a txt file in the desktop too(OutCaptcha).
But it didn't contain the captcha, it had the header of the webpage.("tails of Aut")

Comment: Open the text file manually. What are the whole contents of the text file?

Comment: The whole contents of the File are: 

atails of Aut

Comment: Can you try the powershell file after setting up the PowerShell? Try the script manually to see what you get exactly.

Comment: Sir, i'm unable to get the whole process. I have already run the program twice and did all the steps again and again.
The data which is getting entered into the Captcha Field is "etails of Auth" and i have a ".Png" file on dektop with screenshot of it.

Comment: DId you try to run the program ?
 working for you ?

Comment: Yes of course. The code still tries getting the captcha till it is got well .. as the captcha will not be captured right all the time

Comment: Sir ,Could you please send me a video of your code and steps, if it is possible ?
Mail me at :- amit.shm03@gmail.com

Send me only if you can,  if you can't i understand.

Comment: OK I will try to contact you to show you the steps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very interested to see if you can beat the captcha methodology.  It's not going to be easy, and definitely NOT easy with VBA.  The whole point of using a captcha system is to setup a type of challenge–response-test to determine whether or not the user is human.  That's all it does and it does it very well.

Comment: Hahaha Yes sir i do understand, i was not trying to beat it wholly, but to semi-automate it that's all.

Comment: @ASH I have reached a great point at it but fear to post it ..maybe against the rules :)

Comment: @YasserKhalil Why against the rules sir ?
Also  could you help me in extracting the table information, i have edited the question.

Comment: Because this is considered against the security and the purpose of using captcha.

Comment: You were able to fully automate the captcha process ?
That wud be insane, i have seen methodologies online which use other softwares and also OCR techniques.

Comment: Have a look at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484591/)